# React native can not read property 'prototype' of null

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I updated the react native from 0.59 to 0.63.
I started getting an error says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null`
There is no further detail about the error.
How can I debug to get more detail or how to solve this error?
I have checked the log in React Native Debugger as well but no detail there as well.
[image]

Comment: the image is tiny, can't see from where is that coming from

Comment: I have updated image.

Comment: that error don't explain alot that is android or ios ?. both platforms compine in AS or xcode ?

Comment: Above is ios simulator screenshot.